# Katalon studio github action: is it posible to get the test run id?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I'm using katalon studio github actions as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/katalon-platform/execute/cicd-integrations/katalon-studio-github-action), the tests run as expected but I need to somehow get the results and send them to the Asana.

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Katalon Studio Github Action
      uses: katalon-studio/katalon-studio-github-action@v3
      with:
          version: '9.0.0'
          projectPath: '${{ github.workspace }}'
          args: '-noSplash -retry=0 -testSuiteCollectionPath="Test Suites/Simple Test Suite Collection" -apiKey= ${{ secrets.API_KEY }} --config -webui.autoUpdateDrivers=true'
```

I would like to get the test run id to make a request to katalon testops and send the test results in json format to asana.

If anyone knows a way to get the test id in the github action or how to send the test results in some way to an external API, I would appreciate it.

Note: I would like to have the results of the tests in a more detailed way like in [this example](https://developers.katalon.com/reference/get-a-test-result) and not just know if the tests failed or not.